# how to load an assembly in a new powershell window

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, automation

I am working on a powershell script that zips a folder and then unzip on multiple destinations in parallel with a batch of 10 rather one at a time. I want to open a new powershell window to extract the files on to multiple destinations and close the windows only for the successful unzip operation. I think I am doing good in regards to logic but I am stuck passing the parameters, seems like I am able to load assembly but my variables are not properly recognized on the new window. How do I get this working?

```
$command1= 'Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"'
           $command2= '[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("$zipfilename", "\\$Server\$DestinationLocation")'
           $stringcommand= "-noexit -command $command1 |-noexit -command $command2";           
           $ServerCopyWindows += Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList $stringcommand -WindowStyle Normal
```

Here is the full code that I am working on:

```
    function ZIPFileCopy
    {  
     $sourcedir= Read-Host ("Please Enter the Folder that needs to be Zipped")
     $zipfilename=Read-Host ("Please Enter the ZIP File location and ZIp File name with .Zip extension, Eg.C:\folder\Name.Zip")
  Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
  $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
  [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir, $zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
  $Servernames= Get-Content "C:\ServerNames.txt"
  $DestinationLocation= Read-Host("Please enter the destination location, eg.c$\deployment\")  
  $TotalServers = $Servernames.count  
    for($i=0; $i -le $TotalServers/10; $i++)
    {
        $startLoopCount = ($i) * 10
        if($TotalServers - $startLoopCount -gt 10)
        {
            $endLoopCount = 10
            for( $k=0 ; $K -lt $endLoopCount; $K++)
            {
               $Server = $Servernames[$startLoopCount]
               $Server = $Server.Trim()
               $Server
               $command1= 'Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"'
               $command2= '[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("$zipfilename", "\\$Server\$DestinationLocation")'
               $stringcommand= "-noexit -command $command1 |-noexit -command $command2";           
               $ServerCopyWindows += Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList $stringcommand -WindowStyle Normal
               $startLoopCount++
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $endLoopCount = $TotalServers - $startLoopCount
            for( $k =0 ; $k -lt $endLoopCount; $k++)
            {
               $Server = $Servernames[$startLoopCount]
               $Server = $Server.Trim()
               $Server           
               $ServerCopyWindows += Start-Process Powershell
               $startLoopCount++
            }
        }

        [bool]$stopFlag = $true

        while($stopFlag)
        {
            $stopFlag = $false
            foreach($ServerWindow in $ServerCopyWindows)
            {
                if($ServerWindow -ne $null)
                {
                    if($ServerWindow.hasExited -ne $true)
                    {
                        $stopFlag = $true
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think pipelining the commands passed to PowerShell.exe might be a problem here. Give DMeier_Nera's answer a read on the [Technet Social Site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b32451ea-0767-4a34-b4be-ea7cf9e166a4/run-multiple-commands-using-cmd-with-powershellexe-command?forum=winserverpowershell).

Basically you can define your "script" in a variable like so:

```
$yourscript = {
     Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
     [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("$zipfilename", "\\$Server\$DestinationLocation")
}
```

Then convert your script to a string

```
$command = $yourscript.ToString()
```

Convert to string to an encoded command

```
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes( $command )
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String( $bytes )
```

And execute it

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -WindowStyle Minimized -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

Haven't tested tthis myself, but it should work.